# disable direct file access on lighttpd

Tags: lighttpd, hotlinking

I'll be fast:

Is there a way to block direct file access to files/images on my /var/www? So for example:

If I am loading the page example.com/info.php that contains the image hello.jpg, can I block access to example.com/images/hello.jpg but at the same time allow the loading of said image in example.com/info.php?

So basically enable loading only if it's inside a page but not with the direct link.

Thanks in advance.